# Keycloak not initializing in React when deployed to Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, keycloak

I am using Keycloak as authentication in my React Web Application. When ran in local, it is working properly. But when already deployed in Docker, Keycloak does not initialize.

Here is my Keycloak init code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const keycloak = Keycloak("/keycloak-dev.json");
    keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required'}).then(authenticated => {
      this.setState({ keycloak: keycloak, authenticated: authenticated, roles: keycloak?.tokenParsed?.realm_access?.roles, token: keycloak.token})
    })
  }
```

`/keycloak-dev.json` is in the public folder of my application.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Your code uses the hardcoded value `/keycloak-dev.json` but in your comment you mention `/keycloak.json`, could this be the issue?

Comment: @nicodp sorry typed a wrong file in the comment. already edited

Comment: Can you inspect the Docker logs when you initialize the application? What errors do you get?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72019588/how-to-avoid-timeout-when-waiting-for-3rd-party-check-iframe-message-with-keyc) solved this issue, hope this helps :)